# Scala: Parsing long String with an JSON in it

Tags: scala

I have an Array in scala which looks like:

```
Input = [(KeyID, Field_1, Field_2, { 'id': 1, 'name': 'John'},{ 'id': 2, 'name': 'Dani'})]
```

Essentially, I want to extract the fields: Field_1, Field_2 and the JSON as a field itself:

```
Field_1, Field_2, { 'id': 1, 'name': 'John'},{ 'id': 2, 'name': 'Dani'}
```

I tried to delete the () at the very end and beginning by using:

`Input.replaceAll("[()]","")`

However, sometimes the json also contains parentheses, how to extract the fields independently and how to preserve the json structure?

By trying to split the string, I'm getting:
`Field_1, Field_2, id, 1, name, John, id, 2, name, Dani`

Comment: That's not valid syntax for an `Array`. What exactly is the input data?

Comment: it is: Array[(String, Instant, String, String, String, String)])

Comment: Manual parsing of a JSON string is a Bad Idea (TM). I'm confused by the string replacement, are you operating on a stringified version of this array? I'm pretty confused by the question. Why is the data structured like this? Where is it coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is actually answering the question, but I hope this helps.

Assume you have this data:

```
val Input = Array((KeyID, Field_1, Field_2, "{ 'id': 1, 'name': 'John'}", "{ 'id': 2, 'name': 'Dani'}"))
```

`Array` is a Java type so the first thing to do is to convert to a Scala `List`. Then you can extract the fields using a simple `map`.

```
val input = Input.toList

val keys = input.map(_._1)
val field1 = input.map(_._2)
val field2 = input.map(_._3)
val json1 = input.map(_._4)
val json2 = input.map(_._5)
```

Each `val` will contain a `List` of the particular field.

If you want to process the JSON itself there are various Scala libraries out there to do it. Pick one and then come back if you have specific problems getting it to work.